# How can I replace one variable's array with another?

Tags: c

I have an array through whose contents I need to iterate and prep up a new array. I need to do this multiple times, and I don't need to keep the old data once I'm done with it within the inner loop.

Essentially:

```
double array[dim];
double temparray[dim];

/*initialise array*/

for(...){
    for(...){
        /*replace contents of temparray based on contents from array*/
    }
    array = temparray;
}
```

However, this code breaks:

```
error: assignment to expression with array type
array = temparray;
      ^
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<dim; i++) array[i] = temparray[i];`

Comment: You can also `memcpy`.

Comment: @squemish Is that really the only way? What about pointer manipulation, to allow me to just replace array's pointer with temparray's?

Comment: @Mox No, not the only way (using `memcpy` might be a bit faster, in fact). You can't reassign pointers, and even if you could, you would lose the original data.

Comment: `array` and `temparray` are both arrays, so you cannot assign one to the other. You can however use `memcpy` as tadam says the in the comments, if you don't want to copy element by element.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I don't really care about the original data. I'll mention that in the question.

Comment: You have arrays, not pointers, they're not the same thing. Take a look here: http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? You can obviously write `double* arrPtr = temparray;` but since the array is literally called `temparray` that's maybe not a good idea. The scope of memory allocated by `temparray` cannot be changed.

Comment: If you don't need to preserve the data, then just use two pointers that you swap between two buffers. No need to do slow hard copies. Any answer suggesting that you do a hard copy has not given this question enough thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a couple of helper pointers and swap their values, instead of copying the arrays every time.

So, if I've understood your intent, you can write something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap_dptr(double **a, double **b)
{
    double *tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

#define dim 5

int main(void) {
    double a[dim];
    double b[dim] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5};

    double *pa = a;
    double *pb = b;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; ++j)
        {
            pa[j] = 1.0 - 0.5 * pb[j];
            printf("%10.6f", pa[j]);
        }
        puts("");
        swap_dptr(&pa, &pb);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like something I might be interested in. The swapping of the array pointers in ingenious, as you don't even have to deal with memory leaks.

Comment: Any reason why your temporary pointer is of void type though?

Comment: @Mox Just to be more general (code reuse). You can use the right type, of course.

Comment: @Mox To avoid compiler warnings you may want to cast it  `swap_ptr((void**)&pa, (void**)&pb);`

Comment: @sg7 Good point. The OP may choose to just use double pointers, instead.

Comment: Although it probably will work on most common modern architectures, while `void *` is guaranteed to be big enough to hold a `double *`, the reverse is not true, so `*a = *b; *b = tmp;` is not guaranteed to work. If it does, you can eliminate the casts altogether by having `swap_ptr()` take two `void *`, and converting them to `void **` inside the function.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I see. No, I wouldn't do that, unless it's necessary, and for the OP's use case, it would be just (error prone) noise.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths That's just nonsense. The standard is perfectly clear, C11 6.3.2.3: `A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.`

Comment: @Lundin: So what? That has nothing to with dereferencing a `void **` and attempting to store something at that address when what actually lives there is a `double *`. Imagine what would happen if a `void *` was 8 bytes and a `double *` was 4 bytes, for example. The standard doesn't require all object pointers to be the same size. In your quote, the part about "the result shall compare equal to the original pointer" applies only when you're converting to and back from `void *`. Similarly, you can convert `int` to `char` and back, but you're not guaranteed to not lose information.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths No. Read the cited text again. You are 100% guaranteed not to lose information. It will be very hard to conform to the standard without having all pointers of the same size. In fact, to my knowledge nobody has ever designed such a system in the real world - whenever there exist pointers of different sizes, non-standard `near` and `far` are used.

Comment: @Lundin: you're simply incorrect. Look at C11 6.2.5.28, that talks about precisely which kinds of pointers need to have the same representation and alignment with each other. The only type of pointer that `void *` needs to have the same representation or alignment with is `char *`. Particularly look at the last sentence: "Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements," and are therefore not interchangeable as function arguments or return values, per the footnote.

Comment: Would the arrays being 2D arrays complicate this at all? I'm having issues with the changes made in the inner loop persisting. As in, at the end of all loopage, `array` is still as if it was just initialised.

Comment: @Mox You should be able to adapt the code for that, see e.g. https://wandbox.org/permlink/tBrQcztUhdIJFSo6

Comment: @Lundin I guess that PaulGriffiths's point is also backed up in C11 6.3.2.3 7 *"A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned 68) for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer."*, but I'm definetely not a language lawyer.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Ignore what C allows regarding pointer representation. My point is: how exactly do you plan to conform to 6.3.2.3 unless the pointers are of same size? That's not practically possible. How do you plan to convert a 8 byte pointer into a 4 byte pointer without losing information?

Comment: @Bob__ That's irrelevant since 6.3.2.3/1 is what applies here, not 6.3.2.3/7.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm certainly not going to ignore what C allows regarding pointer representation, since it's critical to the point at hand. As I said, 6.3.2.3 doesn't mandate that a pointer to `void` be convertible to a pointer to another object type and back again without losing information - it only mandates that a pointer to another object type be convertible to a pointer to `void` and back again without losing information. Again, it's no different from being able to convert `char` to `int` and back again without losing information, but not in the other direction.

Comment: @Lundin: The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html) has an answer giving some actual examples of this, including Prime machines where `char *` was bigger than `int *`, and the [DG Nova](http://c-faq.com/null/wierdptrs.ct.html) where a conversion between two different pointer types loses information even though they're of the same size.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you're after.  The code uses the pointers `p1` and `p2` to point alternatively at `array1`/`array2` or `array2`/`array1` respectively.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void dump_array(const char *tag, int num, double *data)
{
    printf("%8s", tag);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf(" %4.0f", data[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    int dim = 10;
    double array1[dim];
    double array2[dim];

    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        array1[i] = i;

    double *p1 = array1;
    double *p2 = array2;

    dump_array("p1:", dim, p1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
            p2[j] = 2 * (p1[j] + 2) + j;
        dump_array("p2:", dim, p2);
        dump_array("array1:", dim, array1);
        dump_array("array2:", dim, array2);
        double *tp = p1;
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = tp;
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
     p1:    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
     p2:    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25   28   31
 array1:    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
 array2:    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25   28   31

     p2:   12   19   26   33   40   47   54   61   68   75
 array1:   12   19   26   33   40   47   54   61   68   75
 array2:    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25   28   31

     p2:   28   43   58   73   88  103  118  133  148  163
 array1:   12   19   26   33   40   47   54   61   68   75
 array2:   28   43   58   73   88  103  118  133  148  163

     p2:   60   91  122  153  184  215  246  277  308  339
 array1:   60   91  122  153  184  215  246  277  308  339
 array2:   28   43   58   73   88  103  118  133  148  163

     p2:  124  187  250  313  376  439  502  565  628  691
 array1:   60   91  122  153  184  215  246  277  308  339
 array2:  124  187  250  313  376  439  502  565  628  691
```

Comment: Would the arrays being 2D arrays complicate this at all? I'm having issues with the changes made in the inner loop persisting. As in, at the end of all loopage, `array` is still as if it was just initialised.

Comment: If the arrays are 2D arrays, you have to be more careful with the pointer types.  With `double array1[dim1][dim2];`, you'd need `double (*p1)[dim2];`, I think — I've not verified that with a compiler.  You should then be able to make appropriate changes to the `dump_array` code and initialize/edit code, and you should be home and dry.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly assign the array to another array. For this problem you have 2 option first one is by using pointer and assign the pointer to other pointer. And second is by using loop and assign the value to another array one by one.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
int array[100],temparray[100];
int i,n;
scanf("%d", &n); // size of array
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
temparray[i]=array[i];
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 printf("%d", temparray[i]);
}
}
```

The above code is just a small example of achieving the goal.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler is right, you cannot assign an array directly. You can initiate it directly and then loop through it to change it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
double temparray[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

void printArrays() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", array[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", temparray[i]);
    }
}

void arrayCopy() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        array[i] = temparray[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Hello, Arrays!\n");
    printArrays();
    arrayCopy();
    printf("Hello, Arrays!\n");
    printArrays();
    return 0;
}
```

There are many ways to illustrate it but I've tried to keep it simple above. It just replaces the elements of one array with another.